# Can't populate object property in uiviewcontroller on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a uiviewcontroller with two properties: trackName and playerObject.  PlayerObject also has a trackName property.  I call this uiviewcontroller from my main uiviewController with this code:

```
SecondaryViewController *nextViewController = [[SecondaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondaryViewController" bundle:nil];
NSString *trackName = @"a track";
nextViewController.trackName = trackName;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
[nextViewController release];
```

In SecondaryViewController I override the initwithnibname method to set the trackName of the playerObject.  I do this with this code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    playerObject.trackName = trackName;
}
playerObject.trackName = trackName;
return self;
```

}

Finally my playerObject has all of the view data the SecondaryViewController will need.  It looks like:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
NSString *s = trackName;
    //more code relevant to the the view controller
}
```

When I debug, the trackName string in the playerObject is nil.  I assume I'm doing something wrong.  How can I have this value populated with the trackName I originally passed in the main uiview controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when you are initing the viewController the playerObject variable has not yet been set, could this be possible?

Comment: Daniel, can I set the trackName in another method besides initwithnibname in the secondaryviewcontroller? If so which method?

Comment: I dont know for what purpose you are using this t rackName, you can maybe set it in view did load or something of the sort? You must set it after you assign the player object tho

Comment: the secondaryviewcontrol doesn't do the loading.  Everything to do with the view  is done in the player object class. trackname is irrelevant I just need to set a property in the object from the original mainviewclass.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen when you override initWithNibName:bundle:.

Instead use viewDidLoad to do setup. Apple guarantees all required setup is performed before this method is called (not the case with initWithNibName:bundle:).